# ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd were not generating during Ajax get call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, scriptresource.axd

I have aspx pages that I am opening on jquery dialog like this:

```
$("a.dialog").live("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div><img src='/Images/loading.gif'/></div>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                modal: true,
                width: 500,   
                position:['middle',20],                 
            })
            .load(this.href);
        });
```

the page is working fine even I can have postback on target page to save the form data.
but when I use update panel on target page its not working.
Getting a closer look I find the ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd  were not generating on the resultant dialog which are required for update panel to cause asynchronous post back.
how can I generate them while doing .load() or can I have any other way to load the page in dialog box